# Name of glossary entries containing command defined with \NewDocumentCommand

Tags: glossaries, xparse

I defined the following latex command:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\invokeWithCSV}{m>{\SplitList{,}}m}{#1#2}
```

It takes as input the name of a command and a list of comma separated arguments and invokes the command using those arguments.
Then I create the command:

```
\newcommand{\sample}[3]{sample text}
```

Now if I try to create a glossary entry with either

```
\newglossaryentry{entry}{
      name=\sample{1}{2}{3},
      description={desc}}
```

or

```
\newglossaryentry{entry}{
      name=\invokeWithCSV{\sample}{1,2,3},
      description={desc}}
```

then the second option fails. Could you explain this and offer a solution for it. The exact command to be invoked and the number of its arguments are unknown beforehand.

A minimal working example with the first option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,pgffor}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
% \NewDocumentCommand{\invokeWithCSV}{m>{\SplitList{,}}m}{#1#2}
\newcommand{\sample}[3]{sample text}

\newglossaryentry{entry}{
    name=\sample{1}{2}{3},
    description={desc}}

\gls{entry}    
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

A minimal NON-working example, just by changing the `name` field:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,pgffor}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\NewDocumentCommand{\invokeWithCSV}{m>{\SplitList{,}}m}{#1#2}
\newcommand{\sample}[3]{sample text}

\newglossaryentry{entry}{
    name=\invokeWithCSV{\sample}{1,2,3},
    description={desc}}

\gls{entry}    
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you expand your code to provide a minimal working example which compiles or a minimal non-working example, if you get an error?

Comment: I changed accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to circumvent the above issuse:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\newentrywithargs}{m >{\SplitList{,}}m}{
    \newglossaryentry{entry}{
        name={#1#2},
        description={desc}
    }
}

\newentrywithargs{\sample}{1,2,3}
\gls{entry}
```

With this command I can create entries whose names are generated by macros with arbitrary number of parameters.

This solution, mind you, doesn't answer the question why my original approach throw an error.